# Phonegap - Not able to install my own custom plugin v3.1

Tags: plugins, cordova, command-line-interface, cordova-3

I am trying to create and install my first plugin in v3.1 but am having problems.

I followed the guides at

```
http://devgirl.org/2013/09/17/how-to-write-a-phonegap-3-0-plugin-for-android/
```

and

```
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins
```

I created my three files

```
plugin.xml
src/android/test.java
www/test.js
```

I then added them to a .zip file so I could install the plugin using the CLI. I then tried to install the plugin using

```
phonegap local plugin add test.zip
```

I am running the command while in the root folder of the app and the .zip file is also in the root (also tried it outside of root) and I get the following error

```
[phonegap] adding the plugin: test.zip
[error] Error fetching plugin: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'c:\workspace\test.zip\plugin.xml'
```

This is strange as there is a plugin.xml file in the root of the .zip file.

Any suggestions to what I may be doing wrong???

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Phonegap CLI requires a git source to add a plugin.

Check your custom plugin into a git repository and try that to add.

Cordova CLI has an option as below

```
cordova plugin add plugin.tar.gz
```

Give a try with cordova CLI.

Comment: thanks. i read that in the tutorial. but is there any way to install the plugin through a local file? or must it be uploaded to the internet?

Comment: The above one is for local file.

Comment: When I try the local install from CLI i get an error saying "is not a node"  if i try "phonegap local plugin add plugin.zip i get the same error as i originally posted. i will try the git repository method

Comment: got it working through git. not sure why it wont work offline though from a local file.